# R web/text mining - web query JSON read

Tags: json, r, web, mining

In the Blekko search engine you can get the search results in JSON format, e.g. with the search term 'lifehacker':

http://blekko.com/ws/?q=lifehacker+%2Fjson

How could you carry out this query from R and parse the content? 
[There is a URL, a RSS URL and a snippet with the main text.]

I have tried packages tm.plugin.webmining and boilerpipeR, but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Rcurl` and `RJSONIO` packages is very handy to retrieve `rjson` results:

```
library(RCurl)
library(RJSONIO)
doc <-  getURL('http://blekko.com/ws/?q=lifehacker+%2Fjson')
doc.ll <- fromJSON(doc)
```

Then you can check the result like this :

```
doc.ll$RESULT
```